# How to create file in a specific path of the server in Java?

Tags: java, file

I want to create a File in a specific path into server in Java Program
I use FileOutputStream but it doesn't work

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
```

the value of filepath is: /home/Folder/bin/QueryGet.sh

message of error is : java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\Folder\bin\QueryGet.sh (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)

I don't know why change "/" in "\" in the path

Comment: You are probably encountering this issue because the server is running under a different account than you are so the /home path is not mapped to the same location on the server's file system

Comment: Are you running on Windows?  Did you verify that the directory exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Comment: Windows uses `\ ` as a directory separator, but also accepts `/`. So you're probably trying to create this file in Windows (hence it translates the slash to a backslash) but the folder `C:\home\Folder\bin` does not exist.